# How could "Would normal people accept a path of immortality given the following, specific restrictions?" be answered, given that it was on hold?

Tags: bug, specific-question, answers, closed-questions

I saw [Would normal people accept a path of immortality given the following, specific restrictions?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/51759/29) bumped to the top of the front page as "answered" despite being "on hold", so got curious.

I got even more curious when I saw that the question was put on hold **2016-08-15 20:53:24Z** but jorfus posted an answer (ID 51783) **2016-08-15 21:15:11Z**, a full 22 minutes *after* the question was supposedly put on hold.

**How could that happen?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a grace period for answers that are in flight when a question is closed, because it's really discouraging and frustrating to spend an hour writing a good, solid answer to a question only to have it yanked away from you five minutes before you click "post".  (That's a general statement; I haven't looked at this particular question.)  So, if an answer is already being written, it can be posted for up to a couple hours after the question gets closed.  You can't start a new answer post-close, though, and if you had one in progress and navigated away from the page for some reason, I don't know if you could go back in your browser and still post.

I think [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91922/162102) is not completely accurate any more, but it's the closest thing I could find to a canonical explanation.  (That post says four hours; I don't know if that's really true.)